# Expose String to Velocity Theme in Liferay for Social Media Tags (Open Graph)

Tags: liferay, velocity, liferay-velocity, liferay-theme

I would like to expose some Strings to the a velocity theme in the liferay framework in order to write some HTTP headers used for social network sharing. What is important is that my Controller has to put these Strings to the velocity theme during the render phase.

How can this be done please?

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a custom hook and add custom variable that will be available in theme. Check this link http://www.opensourceforlife.com/2012/06/custom-velocity-variable-in-liferay-61.html

Comment: The hook kicks in before the MVC Controller though so it won't work. Is it possible to get the output of the JSP and parse it via JSOUP?

Comment: Are the Strings exposed via some service. If yes then we still have a chance by calling serviceLocator to get the service in theme. If the Strings are just created during render phase, I am not sure how to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the utility class [`VelocityVariablesUtil`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/velocity/VelocityVariablesUtil.html) should help you insert some variables or custom helper utilities to be accessed from the template (`*.vm`) file of theme.

You can use the `insertVariables()` method of this class in your controller to achieve what you need.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I'm using an older version of liferay and don't have that class in my classpath

Comment: Which version of liferay are you using? This might be another good reason to upgrade ;-)

Comment: can't you set the strings as request attributes? request and other variables are already available in theme template. May be I am missing something here, but if you can elaborate a little more on what you want to achieve. Thanks